# How to upgrade Ubuntu to 16.04 LTS and not lose network access

Tags: linux-networking, upgrade, ubuntu-16.04

When I upgraded one of my servers to 16.04 LTS I had to adjust network configuration (I use interfaces file) and use the new network interface name. I was lucky that the server runs in a VM and I could access it via the virtual management console. Some of my servers are physical servers at a co-location and they don't have a remote management interface. As soon the upgrade process finishes the machines will become inaccessible via network.

My question is whether there is a **standard/suggested/preferred way to run LTS upgrade via network and not lose network access** to the server after the upgrade is done and the machine reboots?

Another question is whether it is possible to predict the new network interface names before the upgrade and update network configuration in advance.